# Using page adapter without fragments

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Is it possible to use `ViewPager` without fragments?
All examples i could find load several fragments to the ViewPager.

I want to use it similarly to a `ListView`. I would like to create a custom adapter that will inflate a layout according to the position the pager is in.

if it's possible can anyone point me to an example for that ?

Comment: If you use `ViewPager2`, check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67739732/3586084

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes its totally possible.  Since [`ViewPager.setAdapter()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setAdapter%28android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter%29) takes any instance [`PageAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html), you just need to create your own subclass of PagerAdapter (its kinda like subclassing  BaseAdapter or ArrayAdapter that you use in a `ListView`).  just remember, for PAgerAdapter the docs say:

> When you implement a PagerAdapter, you must override the following
>   methods at minimum:

- [instantiateItem(ViewGroup, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#instantiateItem%28android.view.ViewGroup,%20int%29)
- [destroyItem(ViewGroup, int, Object)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#destroyItem%28android.view.ViewGroup,%20int,%20java.lang.Object%29)
- [getCount()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#getCount%28%29)
- [isViewFromObject(View, Object)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#isViewFromObject%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object%29)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 11):

I had the similar problem and it took me some time to figure it out. Posting my adapter here for future reference.

```
/**
 * A page adapter which works with a large data set by reusing views.
 */
public abstract class ListPageAdapter<T> extends PagerAdapter {

  // Views that can be reused.
  private final List<View> mDiscardedViews = new ArrayList<View>();
  // Views that are already in use.
  private final SparseArray<View> mBindedViews = new SparseArray<View>();

  private final ArrayList<T> mItems;
  private final LayoutInflater mInflator;
  private final int mResourceId;

  public ListPageAdapter(Context context, int viewRes) {
    mItems = new ArrayList<T>();
    mInflator = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    mResourceId = viewRes;
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return mItems.size();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isViewFromObject(View v, Object obj) {
    return v == mBindedViews.get(mItems.indexOf(obj));
  }

  @Override
  public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    View view = mBindedViews.get(position);
    if (view != null) {
      mDiscardedViews.add(view);
      mBindedViews.remove(position);
      container.removeView(view);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    View child = mDiscardedViews.isEmpty() ?
        mInflator.inflate(mResourceId, container, false) :
          mDiscardedViews.remove(0);

    T data = mItems.get(position);
    initView(child, data, position);

    mBindedViews.append(position, child);
    container.addView(child, 0);
    return data;
  }

  public void add(T item) {
    mItems.add(item);
  }

  public T remove(int position) {
    return mItems.remove(position);
  }

  public void clear() {
    mItems.clear();
  }

  /**
   * Initiate the view here
   */
  public abstract void initView(View v, T item, int position);
}
```

The viewPager is not updated automatically when the data is changed int the adapter. For that I used

```
pager.setAdapter(null);
pager.setAdapter(myAdapter);
pager.setCurrentItem(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a Kotlin solution. Set an object of this class as adapter of the viewPager-

```
class PageAdapter : PagerAdapter() {
    private val pageLayouts = listOf(R.layout.home_page_1, R.layout.home_page_2)

    override fun instantiateItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int): Any =
        LayoutInflater.from(container.context).inflate(pageLayouts[position], container, false).apply {
            container.addView(this)
        }

    override fun destroyItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int, `object`: Any) =
        container.removeView(`object` as View)

    override fun getCount(): Int = 2

    override fun isViewFromObject(view: View, `object`: Any): Boolean = (view == `object`)
}
```